# How to add firebase admin sdk to laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I want to work with [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) library in my **laravel** project. But I can't understand where to put my `firebase_credentials.json` file so that no one can see it. Moreover which path to replace here

```
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/firebase_credentials.json');
```

Comment: According to code, place firebase_credentials.json just in same folder where your main file is...

Comment: Should the file be in laravel root dir or in the directory where the code is in? I have tried both but gives these error `FatalErrorException in ServiceAccount.php line 16:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' `

Comment: What is in line 16?

Comment: This code -  
`public function getProjectId(): string
    {
        return $this->projectId;
    }`

Comment: a ? before string should be added as migration to php7.1

Comment: I am using php 5.6 what should I add? Is this a bug or is the library is not getting the input file?

Comment: is your php version is v7.1?? if not you cannot use return value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158221/discussion-between-ajoy-das-and-animesh-sahu).

Comment: : ?string introduced in [php 7.1 new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

Comment: check my answer bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps and you are good to go!

make a directory in `storage` directory I prefer `json` and put your firebase-sdk's json over there I recommend `storage` over `public` because you can't access it directly from outside.

Then use it like this way,

```
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(storage_path().'/json/firebase_credentials.json');
```

**For PHP 5.6**

Give a try to this [repo](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have tried it, but the error- 
`FatalErrorException in ServiceAccount.php line 16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' ` and the code is - `public function getProjectId(): string { return $this->projectId; }`. I think there is a version problem with php 7.1

Comment: please post your code or check it you have some syntax mistake here as I'm sure this will work I have successfully implemented this for my recent two apps with Firebase integration

Comment: Can you specify your php version?

Comment: `public function getProjectId(){ return $this->projectId; }` you have extra `:` remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158226/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-ajoy-das).